# How to model a system of equations as a standard linear regression problem

Tags: regression, linear, multivariate-regression

Having a sample of two independent and two dependent variables ([image: formula]), and considering that [image: formula] and [image: formula], and knowing that [image: formula], how can I model this problem as a standard linear regression problem?

Comment: There are several ways.  One reason for choosing among them would be what you assume about the errors: presumably, since you have a sample, you don't expect these equations to hold exactly.  What are you assuming about the deviations? For instance, if the $x_i$ are not random but the $y_i$ are random and independent with common variances, then you can write this as an ordinary univariate regression; otherwise, you likely need a multivariate model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Still haven't figured it out. I am supposed to estimate the four parameters simultaneously.